# How to stop image truncation or reflowing in columns in WebView in Android?

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, webview

I am loading a HTML in WebView in Android which I have divided into columns by giving `column-width` property of CSS. Whenever a large image is encountered in that HTML(which can't be fitted in one column), it breaks down and shown in 2 parts in adjacent columns.

But I want it to show on one column (by scaling down or by any other method) so that it whole image is shown in one column. Is there any way in Android or CSS that how to achieve same thing?